# Unbinding form submit to iframe with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a PHP page with multiple forms, some of which submit to an `iframe` (separate `iframe` for each form) to allow for ajax-like file uploads.  I don't want the user to have to click a "Submit" button after selecting each file, so I am submitting the form using jQuery's `.submit()` function inside of a `.change()` event on the file input element.

The individual file uploads work fine.

However, after all the individual files are submitted, the user must click on a final button that acknowledges they have reviewed the form data as displayed.  This last button is just an independent button.  It is not a submit button, and it is not associated with any form.  When the page initially loads, this button works fine.

However, once the `.submit()` function is called for the file uploads, the final button seems to be bound to the other form's action.

Roughly, the structure of the page is as follows:

```
<form id="finalForm" target="finalTarget" action="uploadFile.php?action=final" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div id="finalSelect">
   <input type="file" name="finalDraft" id="finalDraft" value="file" />
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="finalSubmitButton" />
</form>
<iframe id="finalTarget" name="finalTarget" src="#" style="width:0px; height:0px; border: 0px"></iframe> 

<form id="signForm" target="signTarget" action="uploadFile.php?action=sign" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div id="signSelect">
   <input type="file" name="signPage" id="signPage" value="file" />
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="signSubmitButton" />
</form>
<iframe id="signTarget" name="signTarget" src="#" style="width:0px; height:0px; border: 0px"></iframe> 

<button type="button" id="mainSubmitButton">Submit</button>
```

the jQuery is as follows:

```
$("#mainSubmitButton").click(function(){
     document.location.href='pageName.php';
});

$("#finalDraft").change(function(){
     $("#finalForm").submit();
}
```

after doing a final draft submit, when I click on the `mainSubmitButton` it loads `uploadFile.php`.

Does anybody know why this is happening, and what I can do to correct the problem?

Thanks in advance for your help.
Kate

Answer (score 0):

Return "false" from the button click to cancel any default behaviour.

```
$("#mainSubmitButton").click(function(){
     document.location.href='pageName.php';
     return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, it didn't work.  When I add an alert before the document.location.href assignment, it executes.  But then the redirect from the assignment doesn't execute, and it still directs me to the page from the .submit() action.  So, the .click function is being called, but some other action seems to be overriding it.

Answer (score 0):

the reason for this, I think is because the element **button** you used is acting as a submit button, not as you intended it to act - like a regular button. Just switch it to

```
  <input type="button">
```

and you should be all set.

check out http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/button for more info

Reference [implementation](http://jsfiddle.net/ZZZVB/).

Comment: Even when I change it to <input type="button">, it executes the other form action.